# How to redirect https://www.example.com to https://example.com?

Tags: http, https, dns, github-pages, cname

I currently have a website hosted on github pages with a custom domain through namecheap. The site can be accessed through following URLs:

> http://www.example.com
>
> http://example.com
>
> https://example.com

except

> https://www.example.com

in which case it says that the site is not secure. I have a CNAME record in namecheap for www to point to example.github.io but it only seems to work when I access through http://www.example.com.

Let me know if there is way to solve this?

Comment: Do you have an SSL certificate for your domain?

Comment: My page loaded with __https:// example.com__ do have a SSL certificate through github pages (I haven't explicitly set any). But https:// www.example.com loads with a certificate which only supports github.io links.

Comment: You'll need to make some changes to avoid the cert error. Check the following - https://github.blog/2018-05-01-github-pages-custom-domains-https/